# Texture coordinate Cocos3d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, textures, cocos3d

Here is how I put my texture on my object :

```
_obj = (CC3MeshNode *)[_world getNodeNamed:@"s0"];
_obj.material.texture = [CC3Texture textureFromFile:@"objTextureLayout.png"];
```

My object is loaded from 3DMAX and I don't understand why my texture coordinate (from 3DMax) is lost...

An other problem, I don't understand why my normals is flipped on a simple polygon. What could I've forgotten ?

Any suggestion ? I can post some screenshot or even the model with texture for a best comprehension for anybody who can help me.

Comment: how are you exporting your object? are you using any of the PVRTools like PVRShaman? i suggest previewing your object with PVRShaman first... i used cocos3d and it took me a while to figure out the right settings to export my objects in. I was using maya on a mac, so its a bit different from your situation

Comment: I tried export from 3DMax to collada with Audodesk collada and OpenCOLLADA, then I convert it into pod file Collada2Pod.

Comment: ok i suggest matching your collada export settings with those posted on the cocos3d website [here](http://brenwill.com/2011/cocos3d-importing-converting-collada-to-pod/). they are using the collada plugin for blender but i guess it should be similar to the tool you are using.From my experience with it i realized that there are alot of ways your object could end up being exported wrong so try to follow the instructions on that site carefully.. if it didnt work try posting on the cocos2d [forum](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/). youll have better chances of getting a definite answer.

Comment: i am annoyed that i have read this non-question many times... what is the problem, the flipped normals or something to do with texture... or a request for a tutorial, this can't still be an issue 19 months later can it be?